# Can EFI/UEFI theoretically steal LUKS password?

Tags: boot, mac, disk-encryption, luks, uefi

I usually keep my data private by encrypting the whole hard drive. My previous notebook had BIOS, without UEFI. I have bought macbook, want to install linux in dualboot there. So I wonder if EFI can steal encrypted drive LUKS key. This question is also related to UEFI loaders on windows notebooks.

I don't actually understand how booting process with these new loaders work. They are much more intelligent than BIOS, so I am thinking that theoretically there can be some backdoors.

So the main question is:
Is EFI/UEFI still active on LUKS password prompt? Because if yes it can read keyboard or memory.

Comment: If your threat model includes *firmware vendors collaborating* with whoever is attempting to gain access to your data, I doubt LUKS by itself can help you. Just as an example, what's to say the keyboard controller firmware isn't rigged to save a copy of the first few hundred keystrokes after power-on in some persistent location? IBM could have done that [in 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Selectric_typewriter#Selectric-based_machines_with_data_storage) or so, on a *typewriter*.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Keyboard firmware is not actually a problem, I can connect another keyboard, or my own arduino unlock module that acts as keyboard. The main question: Is EFI/UEFI still active while linux is booting? Because if yes - it can EASILY steal decrypted luks key from memory. Keyboard firmware threat model is quite complicated and anyway I found a workaround.

Comment: You're talking about pre-boot malware, but with the added twist of it being present in the firmware itself. This is *theoretically* possible with both EFI and BIOS. I have not heard of real-world examples of it in either environment, but I also don't follow developments in that area all that closely, so take my lack of knowledge of examples with a very big grain of salt.